# UIPanGestureRecognizer not working on UIImageView

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, uiimageview, uipangesturerecognizer

Well, the idea is to implement the drag and drop functionality on the little circles with characters in them. Seems simple, but I wasn't able to do it at once. The problem is that the UIImageView representing the little circle doesn't react to pans at all. Here is the code I wrote:

```
- (void)createLiterasAndPlacesForThemForCard:(UIView *)frontCard andWord:(NSString *)word;
for (int i=0; i<[word length]; i++) {
    UIImageView * oneChar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LetterFull"]];
    oneChar.frame = CGRectMake(26+i*24, 175, 23, 24);
    oneChar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    oneChar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UIPanGestureRecognizer * oneCharPanGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
    [oneCharPanGestureRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [oneCharPanGestureRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [oneCharPanGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [oneChar addGestureRecognizer:oneCharPanGestureRecognizer];
    [frontCard addSubview:oneChar];
}
```

Here is the hierarchy - I have a viewController that is called "self" above, it contains a scroll view, containing some cards, and each card has it's little circles which can be dragged around. I am getting a warning at the line where I am setting the delegate, but I guess it's not an actual problem.

Here is the code for the "move:" method:

```
- (void)move:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"THE PAN OCCURED");
    float firstX;
    float firstY;

    CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self.view];

    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        firstX = [[sender view] center].x;
        firstY = [[sender view] center].y;
    }

    translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX+translatedPoint.x, firstY+translatedPoint.y);
    [[sender view] setCenter:translatedPoint];
}
```

And I can't see any reaction to the pans - neither in console nor on the screen. Please help me, I can't find the solution by myself, I've already enabled the userInteraction and it didn't help.

Comment: [scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO]

Comment: Thanks for a quick response, but it didn't work

Comment: 23x24 is a very small area, maybe try increasing the area just to see if the touches aren't being caught because they are outside of this area.  If that's the case, I would increase the touchable area by setting the imageView contentMode to "UIContentModeCenter" and increasing the frame by (13+i*24, 152,49,50)

Comment: I've just tried and made the size two times larger. Nothing changed.

Comment: are the cards userinteractionEnabled?

Comment: try deleting [oneCharPanGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];

Comment: Sorry to tell you, it didn't work

Comment: Is your scrollView contentSize big enough to encompass all of its subviews?

Comment: try changing the backgroundColor to something other than clear. For some reason I've had troubles with this before.

Comment: are the imageviews inside of the card bounds?

Comment: I've completely removed the part setting the backgroundColor to clearColor. It didn't work.

Comment: Post more code.  I posted your exact code into a new project and it worked for me

Comment: To Jesse: yesterday I didn't pay too much attention to my code and that was my mistake - the problem was that ScrollView had the content size rect smaller than the actual card. I am sorry for my stupidity. Thank you very much. Maybe you'd like to post your answer not in the comments so I could mark it as a right one.